# Disable horizontal scrolling in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, uicollectionview

How do I disable horizontal scrolling in `UICollectionView`? I tried to add this:

```
self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
```

to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but it didn't work. I want to have only vertical scrolling. I'm not using Interface builder.

Comment: check uicollectionviewflowlayout and set its flow style to vertical

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Storyboard, I believe you may set it from the **Attributes Inspector**. See the screen shot Below:-

[image: UICollectionView Attributes Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement custom Layout for this. For Custom Layout follow this 2 Example, you can get your answer.

https://github.com/mpospese/IntroducingCollectionViews

http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can set vertical scrolling of UICollectionView from UIBuilder also...

Set the scroll direction as Vertical...